# Storing a combination of IDs

Tags: mysql, design-pattern

For my scenario I have already created a <strike>database</strike> *user* id that is auto incremented and they have already put their company id number in the registration. In the registration table both inputs are stored, but I would like to combine both together in a <strike>(database_id)</strike> *(user_id)* + "_" + (company_id) form so that everyone who has signed up for the application is unique in the database. Would this be possible?

Comment: That leaves a lot open. For starters please post the table definition as `CREATE TABLE` statement and the version of MySQL you're using. Also, what is the `database_id` meant to be? Is this for some multitenant application?

Comment: database_id is the id I am assigning to all users that sign up for the application I am creating. It is auto incremented starting at 1 so each user is given a number, but also I want to combine that with the company id that's already assigned to them. Also this version is 6.3.10

Comment: OK, so its actually a user ID and a company ID (misleading names you chose). 6.3.10 is rather the version of MySQL Workbench, I guess. But the client isn't important here. I wanted to know the server version. And the tables' DDL are still missing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the questions is not well formulated, but as far as I got it:

- You have a table containing two columns `user_id` and `company_id`
- You have set the `user_id` to be `AUTO_INCREMENT` (so it's a `PRIMARY KEY`)
- You are willing to change this column to `user_id + "_" + company_id` to make it `UNIQUE`

Answer: **you're doing it wrong**

Both data must not be concatenated.

Instead, what you want is a `(user_id, company_id) UNIQUE KEY`, which can be done with an `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX user_company (user_id, company_id)`.

Thus, the way you want your `AUTO_INCREMENT` to work is not clear. IMO, you should remove it from the `user_id`, and add it on a new dedicated column `id`. Then, when you `INSERT/UPDATE` in that table, you'll have to know the `user_id` you're inserting/updating, which makes sense since that `user_id` is no longer `UNIQUE` to identify a row.